# How can I diagnose my VB.NET program crash during execution?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, error-handling

My program keeps crashing every time I try to run it on another machine other than my own dev system. It runs just fine on mine but crashes on everybody else's when I install and run it.

To make matters worse, it only gives me the generic **"[name here] has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience"**. So i never can find out why and where it is crashing!!!!

http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/6010/ownerror.jpg

The error signature is:

```
  EventType : clr20r3     P1 : [name here].exe     P2 : 1.0.0.0     P3 : 4d5a8bcb     
  P4 : own     P5 : 1.0.0.0     P6 : 4d5a8bcb     P7 : d     P8 : c6     
  P9 : system.invalidoperationexception
```

I even put the **on error goto doh** in the form_load and still I get nothing. Only thing it is loading up on the form_load is **me.show()** and thats it!

If anyone has any insight as to what I could do to figure out what its crashing on then that would be very awesome! :o)

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things to try/consider:

1) Have you checked the Windows application log to see if you can get a more explicit error message?

2) Try commenting out as much initialization code as possible to narrow down your problem.  To me, it sounds very much like an environmental dependency, but you want to eliminate your code first.

3) What differences are there between your machine and others?  Do you have libraries on your DEV machine that are required for runtime (like the VB runtime)?

Comment: When i check the log i can see that it says **.NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting** But i know that i have framework 2.0SP2/3.0SP2/3.5SP1 & 4 installed!

Comment: I have commented out everything but the me.show() in the form_load code but it still has this error. :o(

Comment: The program is only using **framework 2.0** controls and **Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client**.

Comment: Is the Oracle client installed on those machines?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing.

Don't use ON ERROR GOTO ... This is an old way to track error. I don't even know if it works now. yse Try ... Catch instead.

Comment: I replaced it with a try/catch but still no error message other than the generic one.

Comment: It might not be the initialization code itself but rather something found inside your form. Can you describe what's on your form and put the code too? Also, I don't know if me.show is useful in this particualr situation.

Comment: I commented out the **Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client** and it seems to work now. But i am at odds about how to get drivers for the imports client....

Comment: Ask yourself, how did you get it to work on your computer? Is it a driver that you had to install separatly at some point? If you did a setup kit for your project, you might want to include it in. Or at least document it on the minimal specification. You can probably find the information on the net.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that this is usually a problem with a missing/broken app.config file.  It never gets to actually run any of your code that you can watch/track because it never finishes loading the base configuration.

Comment: Did you do anything to correct the problem with the config file then?

Comment: Yes, I would redeploy the original.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in past to trouble shoot a similar problem was to install Visual Studio on a clean windows install and then install my program. This enabled me to see where in my program the error was occuring. In my case it was a missing dll file.

Comment: Good idea but that would require a lot of work to pull off. I don't have those types of resources sadly :o(

Comment: You might want to look into a virtual PC. I have a Image that I use for testing clean installs that is a little less painful than installing Visual Studio on another PC everytime you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be some code in the InitializeComponent that is causing your error.  On your Form.vb, add a handler for the New() event and that should show you the New() method with the initialize component call in there.  Put that code in a try catch block and see if you catch any different errors.

Comment: Hum do you happen to have an example of doing this?